# Query within another query to join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables **mstEmp** and **dailyattendance**. Now I want to run a query

```
SELECT 
  mstEmp.empname, 
  dailyattendance.InTime, 
  dailyattendance.OutTime, 
  mstEmp.teamtype 
FROM 
  dailyattendance ,
  mstEmp mstEmp 
where 
  dailyattendance.HolderName IN (
    select mstEmp.empname from mstEmp where mstEmp.teamtype='$chk' )
```

Here **teamtype** is matched and the corresponding names are fetched from **mstEmp** and then matched with **dailyattendance.HolderName** to display the result.

Answer (score 0):

How about this::

```
 SELECT 
    mstEmp.empname, 
    dailyattendance.InTime, 
    dailyattendance.OutTime, 
    mstEmp.teamtype 

    FROM dailyattendance inner join mstEmp  on (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname)

    where mstEmp.teamtype='$chk'
   group by mstEmp.empname
```

Comment: use disctinct, for which column do u need, the rows not to be repeated?

Comment: For Which column do you want the restriction?show me the resultset

Comment: there just 2 enteries & it is showing me those 2 entries many times.

Comment: i used distinct still no use\

Comment: yaar, put the group by after the where clause na

Comment: gr8 , c u again, sashiks1009@gmail.com